# Angular field updated from succ in subscribe doesn't propagate to the rendered view

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I have the markup like this.

```
<a href="{{testValue}}">
  Clicky here
</a>
```

In the *ngOnInit()* I execute the following code.

```
this.someService.someObservable()
  .subscribe(suc => {
    console.log(suc.resId);
    this.testValue = suc.resId;
    console.log(this.testValue);
  });
```

The output in the console is consequent both times telling me e.g. *se134*. My conclusion is, hence, that I have properly obtained the value form the service and that I'm updating the field as supposed to.

The expected behavior on the page was that the original value would be changed to the one obtained in the callback from subscribe. That doesn't happen.

I tried to googled the binding system of Angular, understanding that it's a very simple issue (I mean, displaying a value loaded in asynchronously is **not** a big deal here). Haven't found anything striking me as deviating from what I already have.

I even tried with different combinations of brackets, e.g. *a [href]="testValue"* and what not. Of course, as expected, that wasn't giving any improvement.

What am I missing?

Comment: Change detection is not called on your component, after the update.try calling cdRef.markForCheck() to force it

Comment: @Andrei If the change detection isn't called, I think I might have bigger problems. It's not my application. I'm just inheriting it from a guy who's leaving the company. Just to test your theory - what is *cdRef* and how do I get to it? Inject it in the constructor? Also, manually calling the change detection seems like a huuuge no-no. I'll try that, of course, but I also wonder if there are other things to try out.

Comment: @Andrei Just tried it out. I injected *ChangeDetectorRef* and called *markForCheck()*. It made no difference to the page and the updated value of the field is still not rendered to the screen. I think it's both good and bad. The former because the change detection is supposed to work automagically. The latter because I have no clue how to kill it.

Comment: The best sollution really depends on the application. Change detection is probably not called because of onPush strategy for this component or one of its parents. It is done for perfomance. So injecting ChangeDetectorRef in your component and calling markForCheck() could be the best solution

Comment: Are you calling markForCheck() in the subscription?

Comment: Can you try to create a demo on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @Andrei Yes, I tried *markForCheck()* inside the method that I pass to subscribe next method.

Comment: btw `<a href="{{var}}">link</a> ` is not supposed to react to value changes. try to use `<a [href]="var">link</a>` instead. This syntax creates binding and tells angular that this value could be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<a [href]="testValue">Clicky here</a>
```

However, there is a problem in your code. You do not unsubscribe from your service. You can use `async` pipe which will automatically unsubscribe for you

controller:

```
testValue: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.testValue = this.someService.someObservable().map(suc => suc.resId);
}
```

template:

```
<a [href]="testValue | async">Clicky here</a>
```

Comment: Not sure if you noticed - I already tried the brackets around *href* with no result. To make it entirely sure, I can try it again in case I missed a typo or something. Also, not sure about the *map* call of yours. I was expecting a call to *subscribe* and then pass a method that is called when *next* result comes up. Is *map* performing a subscription under the hood? What if we get an error and not next response? How do you handle that?

Comment: I tried and, as I mentioned in the question, that didn't help. I also try and learned that the *map* call isn't invokable on my observable object, neither. However, I noticed that the value in the *testValue* is being forgotten. When I try to display it in console as shown in the question, it prints the correct value. But when I print the value using a button, I don't get that in the display. Like if it's only assigned to the field during the cours of the successful next invokation...

Comment: I've located the issue. Turns out, my syntax (which is the same as yours) was correct. However, there's an issue with the services and the original implementer chose to store a realization of the observable in the constructor, so it's not really an observable they're using.